# Magento and Selenium RC testing with database access

Tags: database, magento, testing, selenium

Selenium is frontend test framework, but what if test case touches database e.g. customer registration workflow?

I suppose that fixturing is necessary. Any clues on how to autoload Mage::app() to selenium rc test cases?

Might be also good idea to create separate database for unit test  *magento_unit_tests* like it is made in [EcomDev_PHPUnit](https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_PHPUnit) unit test framework?

Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: So, why you don't create selenium test for customer registration? It is easy to do.

Comment: @WebFlakeStudio Each run those test will create a customer into database. Basically tests after end should rollback made changes.

Comment: Exactly. You should use separate server/database. Database will have the same state before starting each test.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these types of tests are run against a clone of the site with a separate database. You will want to make sure that you backup your database before running tests, this way you can always restore to a known state no matter what type of changes the tests make.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I think cloning and restoring whole database for each test is time consuming. Test cases should be automated - could you explain what do you mean to _clone a site_. Mirrored app? Adding new feature to oryginal site requires moving this feature to mirrored testing app?

Comment: By clone I simply mean a test or QA copy of production as I assume you won't be running against your production site. Restoring a database from a backup is actually pretty simple and can be scripted so that it's very quick. You could have your tests themselves do the roll back, but what happens if they get interrupted halfway through?

Comment: Ah, these basics are of course met. So my question was more like to how to do rollback after each test - make QA Magento setup. I have now some ideas, and I will check them. Thank you @CIGuy for ur help.